# How to load the compressed glb model in SceneKit iOS?

Tags: gltf

I was using GLTFScenekit to load model. but it throws error "Asset contains unsupported required extensions: ("KHR_mesh_quantization", "EXT_meshopt_compression")" and displayed white screen.Any suggestions please.

Need the solution to render the compressed glb file in iOS SceneKit.